# Get a class name for a select state

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem with my script. I will try to explain you.When I click on an item, I need to remove a attr of a span to replace with an another class.

When I click on a item of the list :

- I get the theme Name (ul li **span**).
- If there isn't '-act' at the end of the class name (*default* or *default-act*, I add it to put the selected state.
- For the others items, I remove '-act' to put the unselected state.

In consequence, I need to have an iten with the *theme Name* + '-act' and the others whitout '-act'.

**Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/DQTKX/21/**

**HTML**

```
<section id="createform">
    <ul>
      <li id="theme_1">
        <span class="default-act">Default</span>
        <h3>Default</h3>
      </li>
      <li id="theme_2">
        <span class="food">Food</span>
        <h3>Food</h3>
      </li>
      <li id="theme_3">
        <span class="supermarket">Supermarket</span>
        <h3>Supermarket</h3>
      </li>
      <li id="theme_4">
        <span class="travel">Travel</span>
        <h3>Travel</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    var themeName = $(this).find('span').attr('class');  

    $(this)
        .removeClass(themeName)
        .addClass(themeName + '-act');

    $(this).not('active')
        .removeClass(themeName + '-act')
        .addClass(themeName);
});
```

Nota bene : *By default, the first item have a span with a default-act to have an red icon, and when I clicked on another item, I need to remove the "-act" and add it on the select item.*

## EDIT

So, I've just updated for a better comprehension. Don't worry about supermarket and travel icons. Besides, I removed the class on the

, it was confusion.

http://jsfiddle.net/DQTKX/21/

Comment: Seems like you're making this harder then it is. Just use an active class, and toggle that class -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQTKX/11/) ???

Comment: Are you saying that when someone clicks on li with red span, that span should became green and span that previously was green, should became red?

Comment: I think `$(this).not('active')` should be `$(this).siblings(':not(.active)')`.

Comment: @Barmar - seems to me like there is no `active` class to check for ?

Comment: @adeneo Nope, because, in my css, I have classes default-act, food-act, and I can't create a generic class active.

Comment: @adeneo See `<li class="active" id="theme_1">`

Comment: @FAngel Yes, totaly, there is only one span with a green background, and other need to have a red background.

Comment: What's the relationship between the `active` class on the LI and the `-act` suffix on classes of the spans?

Comment: There isn't link. The active class is for something else. **Edit** The -act change the background position of an image who is on the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    var className = $("span", this).attr("class");
    if(className.indexOf("-act")<=0){       
        $("#createform ul li span[class*='-act']").each(function(){this.className = this.className.replace("-act", "");})
        $("span", this).attr("class", className + "-act"    ); 
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQTKX/22/

But as for me, it is better to do it next way:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    if(!$("span", this).hasClass("act")){
    $("#createform ul li span.act").removeClass("act");
        !$("span", this).addClass("act")
    }
});
```

To make it work, you need to change your css (just some parts are shown):

```
#createform li .default {
    margin: 35px auto;
    width: 69px;
    height: 114px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#createform li .default.act {
    background-position: 0 -114px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<li id="theme_1">
        <span class="default act">Default</span>
        <h3>Default</h3>
      </li>
```

Comment: It's works pretty fine. Thanks a lot! I used the second version, and do some changes on the css. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in a more simple way, so check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DQTKX/13/

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

I also made some changes in your CSS.

Comment: Where do you see a space in `themeName + '-act'`?

Comment: @Omid That's not totaly what I was looking for. I want to do this same selection but with the inner tag <span> and add/remove the suffix -act to the theme name (= default, food, supermarket). I have tried to add a active class, in the span, but it doesn't works with the rest of the css. I will update my jsfiddle, for a better comprehension.

Comment: You mean that you want this functionality for each `span` in `li` tags ? But you have just one span in each one.